# Is my private key available in the Time Machine backups? Where can I find it?

Tags: time-machine, backup, xcode, app-store-connect, code-signing

I've used Time Machine on my Mac to perform backups of my Lion install. My SSD failed and I installed Mountain Lion on my machine.

Now, I want to recover my private key from my backup so I can continue to sign my iOS apps without having to regenerate all of the certificates and provisioning profiles online.

Is my private key available in the Time Machine backups? Where can I find it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Keychain keeps its files inside of ~/Library/Keychains.  In there is a "login.keychain" file that you can add to your current list of keychains in Keychain Access.

Comment: Double clicking adds the old keychain to the system keychain. When I want Xcode to use it, I'm prompted for the password I used when the keychain was created. Simply, it works.